# Understanding output stepAIC

Tags: regression, data-mining, aic

I am using the `stepAIC` function in R to do a bi-directional (forward and backward) stepwise regression. I do not understand what each return value from the function means.

The output is:

```
          Df     Sum of Sq    RSS       AIC
<none>                        350.71   -5406.0
- aaa      1     0.283        350.99   -5405.9
- bbb      1     0.339        351.05   -5405.4
- ccc      1     0.982        351.69   -5400.5
- ddd      1     0.989        351.70   -5400.5
```

Question Are the values listed under `Df`, `Sum of Sq`, `RSS`, and `AIC` the values for a model where only one variable would be considered as the independent variable (i.e. y ~
aaa, y ~ bbb, etc.)?

**NOTE: Question also in data science exchange:**
[data science link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/968/understanding-output-stepaic)

Comment: Why do you have identical versions of this Q cross-posted at both sites? SE frowns on this. (It can be fine to ask *closely related* questions on 2 sites, though.)

Comment: On a different note, why are you using stepwise selection? It is strongly recommended that you do not do this. To understand that further, it may help to read my answer here: [Algorithms for automatic model selection](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/7290).

Comment: @gung I just wanted to get as much exposure as possible. I didn't know this was frowned upon.

Comment: Noting that you have done so is nice, but it would be better to decide where you think your Q best fits, & ask only there. If it doesn't get a satisfactory answer, then you could try to have it migrated.

Comment: I am using stepwise selection because I want to see which variables are the most influential in my linear fit

Comment: Re: your substantive questions, we will need to know more about your data, model, code & output to answer them. Can you add more info?

Comment: Unfortunately, stepwise selection won't do a good job of that, except possibly under ideal circumstances.

Comment: I need to clean it up. I'll have it ready soon

Comment: I have 25 independent variables, 1 dependent variable and I have 2678 observations. 24 of the independent variables range from 0 to 5. The 25th from 0 to 39.

Comment: how do I load text documents to stack exchange

Comment: You can't upload documents to SE. You could upload them to dropbox & link to it, but it is also unlikely someone will download your data & re-run your analysis. Just edit in some info about your data & paste your code & output to start.

Comment: I tried the output is too large

Comment: Perhaps more than this, but less than all then?

Answer (score 4):

After consulting with someone I found out that the "none" category corresponds to a model that would include all the variables, in other words none of the variables were removed. So consider the line in the output for the variable aaa. The listed RSS and AIC are the values for a model that would include all variables but aaa and we see an increase in the RSS and AIC. The other listed results can be considered in the same fashion. The best model is then the one where none are removed since this has the smallest AIC.